# Code Coverage in Intellij 10 CE

Tags: java, junit, tdd, intellij-idea

Is there a community plugin or EMMA tool for Code Coverage in Intellij 10 CE? I know it's available as part of the paid version, but the bigwigs won't spring for it. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's in the enterprise edition.  (Works great for both Java and web projects.)

I ante up for a personal license every year.  It's not too much money, and it's worth having.  If the bigwigs won't spring for it, put your money where your mouth is and buy it yourself.