# Java Code Coverage tool for Idea IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I know that this is already asked([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568534/code-coverage-in-intellij-10-ce)) a long back for the IntelliJ previous versions.

Also some how I have got information on  [even this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182416/intellij-idea-community-edition-code-coverage)

I have tried with the **clover** tool of **atlassian**.

Please suggest any new plugin or tool which I can use with 12.X version of IntelliJ community edition.

Comment: It's about IntelliJ, it can't be a bad question.

Comment: IntelliJ has an inbuilt tool to perform the coverage test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [sonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). It's a pretty slick code coverage tool that allows you to easily and effectively monitor your projects. It has good documentation and isn't hard to configure. You should look into it!

Comment: Could you explain a little on how to perform code coverage in the IntelliJ with Sonar?

Answer (score 4):

I will recommend you to try [Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)

Sonarqube have Code Coverage and many more.

More info:

- [Manage Code Coverage by Unit Tests with Sonar](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project)

Comment: Both of your links are not available anymore.